# Android: How to get a child click in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am having an ExpandableListView that extands BaseExpandableListAdapter.

I want to add a view to child when any child is clicked.

How can i get the proper position of a child when it is clicked? (or how can I add one more child to it).

Comment: It's as obvious as `onChildClick( ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,int childPosition,long id)`

Comment: a group have "isExpanded" boolean variable in  "@Override
 public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
   boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {}" method  .. is there any varible in child view also

Comment: ExapandableListview is only 1 level expandable, you'll have to implement your own NestedExpandableListview...

Comment: Do you know how to get the active child?

Comment: How would you define an active child?

Comment: or when 
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {} method called ???

Comment: I want this --when one child clicked a different layout appears and loded at childview ..

Comment: `convertView` is the Child View, you may set visibility (ON/OFF) of an additional layout within the child layout.

Comment: Thanks , and can you explain how can i do it. it is very important please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try{
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
            new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                    this,
                    createGroupList(),              // Creating group List.
                    R.layout.group_row,             // Group item layout XML.           
                    new String[] { "Group Item" },  // the key of group item.
                    new int[] { R.id.row_name },    // ID of each group item.-Data under the key goes into this TextView.                   
                    createChildList(),              // childData describes second-level entries.
                    R.layout.child_row,             // Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
                    new String[] {"Sub Item"},      // Keys in childData maps to display.
                    new int[] { R.id.grp_child}     // Data under the keys above go into these TextViews.
                );
            setListAdapter( expListAdapter );       // setting the adapter in the list.

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /* Creating the Hashmap for the row */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private List createGroupList() {
          ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
          for( int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; ++i ) { // 15 groups........
            HashMap m = new HashMap();
            m.put( "Group Item","Group Item " + i ); // the key and it's value.
            result.add( m );
          }
          return (List)result;
    }

    /* creatin the HashMap for the children */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private List createChildList() {

        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; ++i ) { // this -15 is the number of groups(Here it's fifteen)
          /* each group need each HashMap-Here for each group we have 3 subgroups */
          ArrayList secList = new ArrayList(); 
          for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n++ ) {
            HashMap child = new HashMap();
            child.put( "Sub Item", "Sub Item " + n );           
            secList.add( child );
          }
         result.add( secList );
        }        
        return result;
    }
    public void  onContentChanged  () {
        System.out.println("onContentChanged");
        super.onContentChanged();         
    }
    /* This function is called on each child click */
    public boolean onChildClick( ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,int childPosition,long id) {
        System.out.println("Inside onChildClick at groupPosition = " + groupPosition +" Child clicked at position " + childPosition);
        return true;
    }

    /* This function is called on expansion of the group */
    public void  onGroupExpand  (int groupPosition) {
        try{
             System.out.println("Group exapanding Listener => groupPosition = " + groupPosition);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(" groupPosition Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For people that are still finding this question, I found the answer to be:

```
listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            ExpandableListAdapter eListAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter)parent.getExpandableListAdapter();
            ListItem item = (ListItem)eListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            return true;
        }
    });
```